# Passing value of check boxes to Javascript from HTML embedded in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom, checkbox

Good afternoon. I am trying to pass the values associated with a list of checkboxes to a javascript function that then calculates the total for all values associated with selected checkboxes.

The HTML code is embedded within PHP. When I try to call the javascript function, I get a null result. Could anyone provide some pointers on where I am going wrong. Code below. All help is appreciated! Thank you.

The variables are pulled from the results of an SQL query executed just before the copied code below.

```
"<form action = 'book.php' method = 'POST'>
  <tr><td>$seat</td>"
  ."<td>$zone</td>"
  ."<td>$price</td>"
  ."<td><input type = 'checkbox' id = 'seat['$seat']' value = '$price'></td></tr>"
  //."<input type = 'hidden' id = '$seat' value = '$price' action = 'checkDetails()'>"
  ;
}

echo "</table>"
      ."Email address for booking ".
      "<input type = 'text' name = 'email id'>"
      ."&emsp;&emsp;"
      ."<button type = 'submit' name = 'book' action = 'book.php'>Book</button></form>"
      ."&emsp;&emsp;"."<button name = 'check price' onclick = 'checkDetails()'>Check Prices</button>";



    } 
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "PDOException: ".$e->getMessage();
    }

echo "<script language = 'javascript'>

  function checkDetails() {
  var seat = document.forms[0];
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < seat.length; i++) {
    if (seat[i].checked) {
        var total = document.getElementById('seat[i]');
        alert('Your total is ' + total);
    }
}
}

</script>";
```

Comment: I would recommend not to output large HTML and JS blocks using echo in PHP. Just end the block instead: `?> write your html/js... <?php some more PHP`. That will make your code _way_ easier to read and debug.

Comment: Also, `id = 'seat['$seat']'` looks like it should cause some problems. You should escape the inner single quotes: `id = 'seat[\'$seat\']'`.

Comment: I think you are right regarding ending the block and writing in pure HTML or JS. We have been taught to echo HTML/jjs within PHP but that makes it so much harder to keep track of code as you said.

What's the benefit of escaping the inner single quotes?

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Echoing HTML and JS using PHP is almost always a bad idea (there are probably cases where it make sense though). It just makes it harder to quite (needs escaping) and IDE's won't syntax highlight the code. The benefit of escaping the inner quotes it to make your HTML correct. If you don't, the `id` tag would stop after the second single quote: `id = 'seat['` and everything after would be considered a new HTML attribute.

Comment: Of course. Still new to this. Thanks for teaching me something new!

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through the forms length.

Since this is rendered in php why dont you set the length of of I programmatically

```
var i;
var length = <?= $seat?>;
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
if ( document.getElementById('seat[i]').checked) {
    var total = document.getElementById('seat[i]');
    alert('Your total is ' + total.value);
}
```

the following code is looping through the form and not the elements

```
var seat = document.forms[0];
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < seat.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Hey, i tired as you suggested and the dev tools in Chrome are showing the value for $seat in the php code as J20 (one of the seat values from the database). Presumably it should be returning some other figure?

Thanks for your help!